# jump animation ending too quickly in first jump

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        if (facingRight == false && moveInput>0)
        {
            flip();
        }
        else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        {
            flip();
        }
        else if (moveInput == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }

        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isGrounded == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("is grounded");
            extraJumps = extraJumpValue;
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps + 1.0f > 0)
        {
            jump();
            extraJumps--;
        }
    }

    void flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
    void jump()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
    }
}
```

I just started to learn unity starting by following tutorials on YouTube. However I can't figure out why my jump animation is ending as soon as it starts on my first jump. On extra jumps it works fine. If you know how to fix this, pls help me.

Comment: Is "moveInput" stil 0 before the 1st jump? It sounds like something neesesary for the proper calcuation is only set *after* the first jump (attempt).

Comment: or that your OverlapCircle is a little bigger? So even when you jump, the time to separate the character more than the distance of the circle is greater than fixedUpdate?

Comment: thanks guys for suggestions Ive checked both and the checkRadius is set up to 1e-05 and yes moveInput was still 0...

Comment: What is extraJumpValue

Comment: It was 1 since I wanted the player to do double jumps. I also checked with other values too but still not working -_-

Answer (score 1):

In your update loop you call Jump which sets

```
    anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
```

and in your fixed update loop you have

```
    anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
```

So immediately after calling Jump on the next 'FixedUpdate' you are setting the animation bool of iswalking, unless moveInput is 0. I can't see all your code or what is happening to moveInput but I can tell you this is where your problem is. You need to change the animations of this code:

```
    anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);
    if (facingRight == false && moveInput>0)
    {
        flip();
    }
    else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
    {
        flip();
    }
    else if (moveInput == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
    }
```